# dnu wrap not creating wrap folder

Tags: asp.net-core, dnu

I have a vNext project that uses dnu wrap to reference an old style class library.  Everything works on 4 machines but one machine is giving me trouble.  I have reinstalled from the OS up and still have the problem.

I get the error:
Failed to resolve references for

> C:\Projects\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj.

I know the path is correct.  I can copy it and then paste it in a file open dialog and the file opens.

I have noticed that on this one machine the wrap folder it not created in the solution root folder.

In my asp.net 5 project.json I have this line:

```json
"scripts": {
    "prerestore": [
      "dnu wrap ../DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj"
    ]
},
```

My global.json has this:

```json
"projects": [
    "wrap"
],
```

**Update:**
I added the -v flag to dnu wrap for verbose logging.  I get this message:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project DataAccess.csproj.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='debug' Platform='MCD'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

This works on 4 other machines.  It's just this machine that's not working.

I do have a solution file.

Looking at project properties I see the output path for the DataAccess project is set to bin\Debug.
I looked in the csproj file and I see and OutputPath tag with the value bin\debug (for the debug build), and another with bin\Release (for the Release build).

Comment: Try adding a verbose flag `dnu -v wrap`

Comment: Done.  I updated the question.

Comment: It says configuration Debug, Platform MCD. What's MCD?

Answer (score 0):

The error message showed Platform='MCD'.  This is an environment variable set by HP on that one HP laptop.  None of out other machines had this and none were HP.  I deleted this variable and it solved the problem.

I don't know what that variable is for and I am not sure why HP added it.  Something else may break but I don't use the vendor installed tools.

I am don't know why dnu is using this variable when the other boxes don't have it.